# c++ int to char

Tags: c++, ascii

I have a list of ints i ([0,255]) and I want to convert these ints to chars.

```
int i;
char c = (char)i;
```

When I print c (when i=0) I do not get the correponding ascii symbol.
How to do the mapping correctly ?

Comment: ASCII `0` is the null-terminator, so nothing at all prints.  Do you want it to print "`0`"?  If so, you can do `c = '0' + i;`, but what do you want it to print for values above 9?

Comment: See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii#ASCII_printable_characters

Comment: what I want it to compare vector of ints as vector of chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing ASCII values with int values... Look at an ASCII table and you'll understand. To print a '0' you need to print the value 48 (decimal). To print values from 0 to 9 you can simply add 48 to the int value and you'll get the correct ASCII code. To print values longer then one digit you need some kind of conversion from one int to several ASCII codes. A google search should find such a function.

Comment: Allright, in fact I have looking for this mapping function. tx.

Answer (score 4):

There is no symbol for ASCII 0.  All the ASCII values less than 32 are control characters.

Comment: With that said, many programs allow an escaped sequence to indicate it, so he could create an array of strings and print the escape sequence...

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a meaningful ASCII symbol for the value 0. It's a NULL character and shouldn't print anything. Why not try printing a value when `i = 97` ('a'), for instance?

If you examine [an ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), you'll realize that not every ASCII character has a meaningful printed value.

Comment: The problem is the following: I worked on vector<int> and the algorithms I want to use work on vector<char>. I would like a mapping function to convert it. Assuming my ints belong to [0,255].